# How do I increase MariaDB performance on Ubuntu 18.04 running on Hyper-V?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, hyper-v

Dear Ubuntu MariaDB & Hyper-V Gurus,

I have a big SQL report running on 4 different MariaDB installations. But two of them running on Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 Hyper-V runs significantly slower, even if HW is amazing.

Is there some SIMPLE flag or value that I have missed in the MariaDB setup, like using many threads or similar, that is not enabled out of the box?

I think I have tested almost every suggestion here and there on query-cache-* or innodb-buffer-* settings, but the results are steady - slow:

Dedicated (old) Windows Server 2016, 4 3.6GHz cores/4 threads, 16GB mem, MariaDB 10.4 for Windows, report runtime = ca **2 minutes**

Windows 10 Hyper-V, Ryzen 3900X 3.6GHz, allocated 6 cores/12 threads, 16GB mem, VM Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and MariaDB 10.1.43 std (apt-get) installation, report runtime = ca **13 minutes**

Windows 10 Linux Subsystem (WSL), Ryzen 3900X 3.6GHz, 12 cores/24 threads, 64GB mem, subsystem running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and MariaDB 10.1.43 std (apt-get) installation, report runtime = ca **13 minutes**

Odroid XU4 8 core/8 threads, 2GB mem, running Ubuntu 16.04 and MariaDB 10.0, report runtime = ca **65 minutes**

Please, "tuning" the report, or suggesting other HW, is NOT the scope of this question!

There must be something simple that I have overlooked in the Hyper-V/WSL setups of MariaDB. "top" shows all the right values for cores and memory. But it seems to me as MariaDB only uses one core in Hyper-V?

Comment: Are you sure the database schema is the same for all the tables involved? Missing indexes etc

Comment: Yes! They are created equally from the very same full prod backup.

Comment: How us the query, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.  The slowest one was running on the oldest version of MariaDB?  Sounds like some Optimization improvements have been made.  So include `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- that is likely to point at what changed.

Comment: Also, I would _guess_ that the oldest was I/O-bound, but the others were mostly CPU-bound.

Comment: We have the same issue: we have a test db on HyperV where one test run requires ~8-10s; the same setup (copied over VMs to make sure no settings are different) on Esx are ~3-4s - Even weirder: having a Galera Cluster on HyperV and using a load balancer increases time on hyperV +2s; on esx its hardly noticable (~ +0.2s).